# Error C2660 : function does not take X arguments

Tags: c

I am converting some legacy C code to C++.

A header file contains a macro P

```
#ifndef P
# ifdef __STDC__
#  ifndef __HIGHC__
#   define USE_ANSI_PROTOTYPES
#  endif
# endif
# ifdef __sgi__
#  define USE_ANSI_PROTOTYPES
# endif

# ifdef USE_ANSI_PROTOTYPES
#  define P(s) s
# else
#  define P(s) ()
# endif
#endif
```

In my case the `USE_ANSI_PROTOTYPES` evaluates to not defined.

Another header file uses the macro P in a function declaration.

```
extern void long2str P((unsigned char *str,int pos,long clong));
```

The function is then called at certain places in code like

```
long2str(tmp_str, 0, seg_used(seg)); // <= error on this line
```

However VS2012 flags error on lines where the function is called

> error C2660: 'long2str' : function does not take 3 arguments

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Expands to `extern void long2str ()((unsigned char *str,int pos,long clong));` How are you using that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ are you sure it doesn't expand to `extern void long2str ()`?

Comment: @tkausl Yes you're right. Should be used like `extern void long2str P(???)(unsigned char *str,int pos,long clong));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using a C compiler from the 1980s, you should make sure that the first branch of the `#ifdef` is taken.

In this case, find out why the `USE_ANSI_PROTOTYPES` is not defined. And then either define it or remove the `#ifdef` section and define the `P` macro unconditionally.

The Microsoft compiler doesn't define the `__STDC__` macro (for whatever reason), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx.

*Explanation:*

Back in the 1980 (before ANSI C89 and ISO C90), functions were declared like this:

```
extern void long2str ();
```

That's it. No parameter names, no types, just the function name (and if you are lucky, the return type).

ISO C90 introduced function prototypes, and the preferred way of declaring functions became:

```
extern void long2str (unsigned char *str,int pos,long clong);
```

The `P` macro from your question can produce both variants when it is called with the parameters in double parentheses. The outer parentheses form a single macro argument, and the inner parentheses are only needed in the C90 case.